# Session is not working

Tags: php, session

I'm showing images from database . i'm giving option to user to short some images as their input . when the user input some number photos will short according to input .

```
<?php session_start();?>

 <?php
          include "script/db_script.php";
          if(isset($_GET['value1']) && isset($_GET['value2'])){
            $value1 = $_GET['value1'];
            $value2 = $_GET['value2'];
            $_SESSION['value1'] = $_GET['value1'] ;
            $_SESSION['value2'] = $_GET['value2'];
             }
            if(isset($_SESSION['value1']) && $_SESSION['value1']&& 
isset($_SESSION['value2'])&& $_SESSION['value2'] ){
                      $sql =  "SELECT * FROM new_photos WHERE weight BETWEEN 
         $value1 AND $value2";
             anjaan($sql);
             echo "<p>Showing images from $value1 gm to $value2 gm</p>";
             }
             else{
                    $sql='select * from new_photos';
            anjaan($sql);
            echo "<p>Showing all images </p>";}
              ?>
```

my form is

```
         <form method="GET">
         From  <input style="width: 50px;" name="value1" = type="number"<br>
         To    <input style="width: 50px;" name="value2"type="number"><br>
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
                                    </form>
```

my problem is when i click on next page on pagination form variable not setting as session.

this code is working fine

```
  <?php
    include "script/db_script.php";
        if(isset($_GET['sort'])){
     $_SESSION['sort'] = $_GET['sort'] == '5_15';
     $_SESSION['sort1'] = $_GET['sort'] == '1_10';
        }
            if(isset($_SESSION['sort']) && $_SESSION['sort']){
                    $sql =  'SELECT * FROM new_photos WHERE weight BETWEEN 5 AND 15';
             anjaan($sql);
             echo "<p>Showing images with 5gm to 15gm</p>";
             }
            elseif(isset($_SESSION['sort']) && $_SESSION['sort1']){
                    $sql =  'SELECT * FROM new_photos WHERE weight BETWEEN 1 AND 10';
             anjaan($sql);
             echo "<p>Showing images with 1gm to 10gm</p>";
             }
             else{
                    $sql='select * from new_photos';
            anjaan($sql);
            echo "<p>Showing all images </p>";}
              ?>
```

form

```
            <form method="GET">
                         <select name="sort">
                            <option value="all">All</option>
                             <option value="1_10">1 gm to 10 gm</option>
                             <option value="5_15">5 gm to 15gm</option>
                            </select>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
                                    </form>
```

Comment: did you open session  ?

Comment: Refer this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: rewrite your html properly and try once again, there is extra `=` sign and space between attributes are not proper.

Comment: *my problem is when i click on next page on **pagination** form variable not setting as session.*, where is your pagination code? Please include the relevant HTML and PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open session first before you use them:

On top of your page before any HTML add :

```
 <?php
 // Start the session
 session_start();
 ?>
```